# Android JNI pthread_create "too many arguments, expected 1"

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

Every time I've ever used `pthread_create` in my life it's required four parameters. For some reason, when trying to create a thread in C while working with android and JNI, I'm seeing this:

[image]

What happened to

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

and why am I not seeing it?

**Edit:**

What's even weirder is that I opposite clicked on my `#include <pthread.h>` and clicked `Go to->Declaration`, and scrolled down till I saw `pthread_create` and it's showing the proper function definition.

**Edit 2:**

Even stranger, I realized now that it compiles fine. It's something with the editor. If I type out four arguments, it says in editor "Expected 1 argument", but it compiles without any issues. However, if I supply only 1 argument like the editor wants, it fails to compile saying "Expected 4 arguments" in the error log.

I have no idea what's going on with it.

Comment: C functions have prototypes and definitions, not signatures.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, updated.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?  It looks like an incorrect declaration for `pthread_create()` exists somewhere, likely in a header file.

Comment: @AndrewHenle check my last edit. I feel that the editor is just being weird for some reason. I've also done a full project search including external headers with no results for additional definitions of `pthread_create`

Comment: Which editor is this?

Comment: @AlexCohn android studio

Comment: which version of AS?

Comment: @AlexCohn Version 2.3.2

Comment: It does not reproduce here. Sometimes, AS requires "Invalidate Cache/Restart" (in **File** menu)

Comment: @AlexCohn I tried running "Invalidate Cache/Restart" as you suggested with no change :/

Comment: :( *and Stack Overflow insists that I make a comment longer, but I really have nothing to say except to empathize with your disappointment*. In such situations I usually reinstall my tools; note that AS 2.3.3 is available on the Stable channel, but I doubt that it will fix this particular behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Android Studio is very unhappy about **_Nonnull** used now in NDK r15. You can choose the GCC compiler

```
android { defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { 
   arguments "NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9" 
}}}}
```

or you can disable the new [Unified Headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r15-release/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md):

```
android { defaultConfig { externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild { 
   arguments "APP_DEPRECATED_HEADERS=true" 
}}}}
```

Or you can switch to [NDK r14](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html) or earlier.

I have opened an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62529380) for Android Studio/C++ dev.

Comment: So, it turns out I was already using r14 but i had unified headers enabled for something else that I no longer need. After I removed it it resolved the issue, thanks again Alex!

Answer (score 0):

Need insert temporary definition

```
#ifndef _Nonnull
#define _Nonnull
#endif
```

to pthread.h for prevent show error from Android Studio.